# sqlite3 INSERT INTO UNION SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, insert

```
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT "hello" AS field1, 15 AS field2, 1262340000 AS timestamp 
    UNION 
    SELECT "byebye", 10, 1262340000 
    UNION 
    SELECT "hi", 20, 1262340000 
    UNION 
    SELECT "boo", 25, 1262340000
```

Table columns:

```
field1  field2  timestamp   pk
```

`pk` is the auto-incrementing primary key

An error occurs when I execute this SQL

> DB Error: 1 "table table1 has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly specify which columns in `table1` your insert is targeting:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, timestamp)
SELECT 'hello', 15, 1262340000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'byebye', 10, 1262340000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'hi', 20, 1262340000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'boo', 25, 1262340000;
```

When you omit the select list entirely, SQLite will fall back to expecting values for *all* columns in the table, in the exact order specified by the table definition.  In your case, as you only provided values for 3 out  of the 4 total columns, you get an error.  Note that you could have also used `VALUES` here:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, timestamp)
VALUES
    ('hello',  15, 1262340000),
    ('byebye', 10, 1262340000),
    ('hi',     20, 1262340000),
    ('boo',    25, 1262340000);
```

Comment: INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, timestamp)
SELECT  this is ok ,thank you!